# Share VPN connections between two Virtualbox VMs

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, vpn

In my work I use a Linux VM (Lubuntu) and the openconnect software to connect to 2 VPNs that provide access and routes to access several Linux machines inside corporate network. Sometimes I do need to open up a Windows VM to access Windows machines and authenticate with a smart card, to connect to VPN I use Cisco Anyconnect software. I've found that in Windows I can either connect to either of the two VPNs endpoints.

What I would like is to connect from my Windows VM to my Linux VM so that it shares the connectivity so that I don't have to reconnect each time I need to check Windows machines.

I've already tried setting up bridge networking under Linux, and NAT on Windows, under Win I can ping the Linux box, but when trying to reach (using IP) the Linux VM, it doesn't connect.

Could somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try this
Use NatNetwork. Setup your vpn in linux vm. In windows vm change proxy settings to point linux machine's ip and vpn's port